# Dojo/Dijit TooltipDialog.open: How to override offsetHeight and offsetTop values

Tags: javascript, dojo, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

Currently trying to implement/solve an issue with an ESRI ArcGIS map environment where I have a multi-layered map with custom graphics being rendered in each layer. Some of the graphics are simple shapes such as lines and circles, but a majority of the graphics are icons (.png) files that are being drawn on the layers. (All of this is being done in JavaScript.)

I have been able to get all of the layers generated correctly - the data IS NOT being stored in ArcGIS maps but a custom designed Contact & Location database (SQL) and other forms within the web application maintain this C&L data.

The graphic icons that are rendered on the map need to have a mouse-over tooltip popup appear with information that has been stored with the icon when it is created where the `.substitute()` command will update the template. The information displayed is HTML formatted in a `<div>`.
Problem:
When the mouse is moved over an icon, the tooltipDialog appears but 1) it always appears in the lower right corner of the screen - despite "orient:" and specific "x:" and "y:" coordinates being specified. Additionally when the `tooltipDialog.open()` command is executed, the dialog's `offsetHeight` is set to 624 and the offsetTop is set to 502. (The `offsetWidth` is actually set to the correct value.) How do I override either/both the `offsetHeight`/`offsetTop`?

I have tried specifying additional parameters to the `tooltipDialog.open()` command but nothing tried so far has altered the outcome. Even when I change the template content to be as simple as "Hi There!" does not change the outcome.

Note: If I click on an icon the `IconWindow` dialog will popup with the proper content and formatting being displayed. So it leads me to believe that the issue is within CSS or some other aspect of dojo/dijit as the `tooltipDialog.open()` command is actually where the offset changes are being made - the values are retained (`offsetTop=0 offsetHeight=0`) prior to the `open()` call.

Ideas/Recommendations?

Comment: Please share some code on how you are creating a tooltip dialog and how you are showing it.

Comment: You can position elements using css. Since you have provided zero code, we can't help you any further.

Comment: can you create a sample or jsfiddle for it...

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the `dijit/popup` module to open the `TooltipDialog`, which would allow you to pass in the DOM node around which the tooltip should be opened:

```
popup.open({
    popup: myTooltipDialog,
    around: dom.byId('thenode') 
});
```

There a full example of this [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/TooltipDialog.html) (next to "A TooltipDialog may be popped up from any node.")

Comment: Looks like the problem I am having is that dijit is duplicating closing tags for within the innerHTML... The tooltip has 8 <div> tags but 15 </div> tags... is there a way to turn off auto-correct or auto-formatting?

Comment: Can you please help me out in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69642934/get-click-of-corresponding-map-marker-in-react-js I am unable to open pop up and display corresponding custom details on point marker on map

Answer (score 0):

Well, It seems like you want to show info popup with some offset value whenever you hover on any feature on the map.

**Solution-**

Well to do so i don't think you need to deal with TooltipDialog because whenever you are loading feature or feature layer on the map you can attach info popup to it. It will take care of entire loading and displaying info popup Dialog along with its positioning.

***To pass offset value-***

If want to pass some offset value to popup dialog you can use below mentioned properties:-

[image]

For more Properties of popup dialog refer this link- https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/popup.html

**Hovering Dialog sample-**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <title>Feature Layer - display results as an InfoWindow onHover</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.18/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.18/esri/css/esri.css">
    <style>
      html, body, #mapDiv {
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        height:100%;
      }
      #mapDiv {
        position: relative;
      }
      #info {
        background: #fff;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
        left: 1em;
        padding: 0.5em;
        position: absolute;
        top: 1em;
        z-index: 40;
      }
    </style>

    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.18/"></script>
    <script>
      var map, dialog;
      require([
        "esri/map", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
        "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol", "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
        "esri/renderers/SimpleRenderer", "esri/graphic", "esri/lang",
        "esri/Color", "dojo/number", "dojo/dom-style",
        "dijit/TooltipDialog", "dijit/popup", "dojo/domReady!"
      ], function(
        Map, FeatureLayer,
        SimpleFillSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol,
        SimpleRenderer, Graphic, esriLang,
        Color, number, domStyle,
        TooltipDialog, dijitPopup
      ) {
        map = new Map("mapDiv", {
          basemap: "streets",
          center: [-80.94, 33.646],
          zoom: 8,
          slider: false
        });

        var southCarolinaCounties = new FeatureLayer("https://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/3", {
          mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_SNAPSHOT,
          outFields: ["NAME", "POP2000", "POP2007", "POP00_SQMI", "POP07_SQMI"]
        });
        southCarolinaCounties.setDefinitionExpression("STATE_NAME = 'South Carolina'");

        var symbol = new SimpleFillSymbol(
          SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
          new SimpleLineSymbol(
            SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
            new Color([255,255,255,0.35]),
            1
          ),
          new Color([125,125,125,0.35])
        );
        southCarolinaCounties.setRenderer(new SimpleRenderer(symbol));
        map.addLayer(southCarolinaCounties);

        map.infoWindow.resize(245,125);

        dialog = new TooltipDialog({
          id: "tooltipDialog",
          style: "position: absolute; width: 250px; font: normal normal normal 10pt Helvetica;z-index:100"
        });
        dialog.startup();

        var highlightSymbol = new SimpleFillSymbol(
          SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
          new SimpleLineSymbol(
            SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
            new Color([255,0,0]), 3
          ),
          new Color([125,125,125,0.35])
        );

        //close the dialog when the mouse leaves the highlight graphic
        map.on("load", function(){
          map.graphics.enableMouseEvents();
          map.graphics.on("mouse-out", closeDialog);

        });

        //listen for when the onMouseOver event fires on the countiesGraphicsLayer
        //when fired, create a new graphic with the geometry from the event.graphic and add it to the maps graphics layer
        southCarolinaCounties.on("mouse-over", function(evt){
          var t = "<b>${NAME}</b><hr><b>2000 Population: </b>${POP2000:NumberFormat}<br>"
            + "<b>2000 Population per Sq. Mi.: </b>${POP00_SQMI:NumberFormat}<br>"
            + "<b>2007 Population: </b>${POP2007:NumberFormat}<br>"
            + "<b>2007 Population per Sq. Mi.: </b>${POP07_SQMI:NumberFormat}";

          var content = esriLang.substitute(evt.graphic.attributes,t);
          var highlightGraphic = new Graphic(evt.graphic.geometry,highlightSymbol);
          map.graphics.add(highlightGraphic);

          dialog.setContent(content);

          domStyle.set(dialog.domNode, "opacity", 0.85);
          dijitPopup.open({
            popup: dialog,
            x: evt.pageX,
            y: evt.pageY
          });
        });

        function closeDialog() {
          map.graphics.clear();
          dijitPopup.close(dialog);
        }

      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body class="tundra">
    <div id="mapDiv">
      <div id="info">
        Hover over a county in South Carolina to get more information.
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

***Hoping this will help you :)***

*However its always recommended to add your code here if you are looking for exact Fix.*

Comment: Understood - it's not as simple as cut & paste for the code.

Comment: Yeah.. Sometimes it happens.. Hoping above answer give you some hints...

Comment: Instead of entire code.. Just small snippets may also leads towards the exact issue or hint for the person who is answering...

Comment: Understood. The code or snippet would have to be re-typed and could lead to syntax error since the test network this project is being worked on has no internet connectivity. (Been trying to work with ESRI on this issue but to little avail... Upgraded to their 3.18 JS API but problem still persists. Not sure if JQuery or Site.Master are interfering with the display of the tooltipDialog -- dialogs appear to be referencing the draw point as being bottom left of map - despite X/Y coordinates displaying in debugger fine.

Answer (score 0):

> Found the answer to my situation. There is what appears to be an unstated requirement that either one of the supplied CSS dijit/themes be utilized OR the user must create their own theme which has some CSS that configures the display location.
>
> The offsetTop issue was resolved by using eliminating any style references to top:.